# AVCaptureSession un-expectedly triggers AVCaptureSessionWasInterruptedNotification, can't figure out source of interruption

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I have a video camera video constructed similarly to Apple's AVCam demo.  I've come across a very frustrating problem that which I don't know how to go about debugging.

Basically, we're talking about a video camera setup on a viewcontroller.  When the VC appears, the previewlayer should show what the camera sees, and upon pressing the record button, starts recording to a file.

This works 20% of the time.  The rest of the time, the VC loads up normally, but the preview layer freezes after 1-3 seconds.  Once frozen, I get no crashes or errors thrown **[EDIT: Not true, see below]**.  However, if I hit record after it has frozen, which triggers a call to

```
[self.fileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:currentVideoURL recordingDelegate:self];
```

I immediately recieve a call to the AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate method

```
-(void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
```

The NSError object is set, with an error code of -11803 {AVErrorSessionNotRunning}.  This method has certainly run after [captureSession startRunning] has been called.

**UPDATE**

Something is causing the session to become interrupted immediately.  captureSession.isInterrupted is set to TRUE almost immediately after capture has begun, and the following notifications fire immediately when I start the session:

```
AVCaptureSessionWasInterruptedNotification
AVCaptureSessionDidStopRunningNotification  (edit -- had the wrong const here)
```

What could cause the session to become interrupted immediately after starting?

Is there any documentation on all the events that could cause an AVCaptureSession to be interrupted?